# Slider covering mega drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, slider

If you could kindly hover your mouse over the *MORE* button in the menu here:
http://jsfiddle.net/H8FVE/3/
You will notice that the big wide picture underneath (#featured) is covering the drop down div. Why and how can I fix it?

Here is part of my HTML code:

```
<div id="second-menu" class="clearfix">
    <ul id="secondary-menu" class="nav sf-js-enabled">
        <li class="manimation"><a href="" style="width:400px;border-bottom:9px solid #43cf61">Animation</a></li>
    </ul>

<ul id="mega">
    <li class="dif mmore" style="background:none;"><a href="#" style="font-style:italic;border-bottom:9px solid #4b5571">More...</a>
      <div>
    <ticman>
    <ul>
        <li class="mgames"><a href="" style="border-bottom:9px solid #e34328">Games</a></li>
        <li class="mliterature"><a href="" style="border-bottom:9px solid #2c8f83">Literature</a></li>
        <li class="marts"><a href="" style="border-bottom:9px solid #cc226a">Arts</a></li>
        <li class="mcontact" style="background:none;"><a href="" style="border-bottom:9px solid #9395aa">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ticman>
        <h2>Classes</h2>
        <p><a href="#">Times</a><a href="#">Schedual</a><a href="#">Map</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Names</a><a href="#">Study</a><a href="#">Directions</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Health</a><a href="#">Dance</a><a href="#">Biology</a></p>
        <h2>Teachers</h2>
        <p><a href="#">Billy</a><a href="#">Madeleine</a><a href="#">Lauren</a><a href="#">Steve</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Paddington</a><a href="#">Stefan</a><a href="#">Michael</a><a href="#">Madeline</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Shannon</a><a href="#">Mary</a><a href="#">Raffaello</a><a href="#">Lorence R</a></p>
        <h2>Location</h2>
        <p><a href="#">Carlsbad</a><a href="#">Oceanside</a><a href="#">El Cajon</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Vista</a><a href="#">La Costa</a><a href="#">Encinitas</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">San Diego</a><a href="#">Los Angles</a><a href="#">Cardiff</a></p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- end #second-menu -->


<div class="et_cycle" id="featured">
    <a href="#" id="left-arrow">Previous</a>
    <a href="#" id="right-arrow">Next</a>

    <div id="slides" style="position: relative; background-image: none;">
                                    <div class="slide" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 3; opacity: 1; display: block;">
                        <img width="958px" height="340px" alt="10 moments in cinematic history changing faith" src="http://ftframes.com/delheat/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/et_temp/ip-man-donnie-yen-756651_958x340.jpg">                <div class="featured-top-shadow"></div>
                <div class="featured-bottom-shadow"></div>    
                <div class="featured-description">
                    <div class="feat_desc">
                        <p class="meta-info">Posted by <a rel="author" title="Posts by admin" href="http://ftframes.com/delheat/wordpress/?author=1">admin</a> on Aug 9, 2012</p>
                        <h2 class="featured-title"><a href="http://ftframes.com/delheat/wordpress/?p=43">Some random text here</a></h2>
                        <p>Well, I like this trailer a bit better than Chasing Mavericks’. Well for one, Gerry gets to keep his Scottish brogue, wahoo! Plus, I kind of like seeing him with kids. I mean the last time he played dad to a little boy was in the wonderful indie Dear Frankie, and he’s definitely a natural with them. Then there’s the supporting cast: Catherine Zeta-Jones, Jessica Biel, Uma Thurman, Dennis Quaid and...</p>
                    </div>
                    <a class="readmore" href="http://ftframes.com/delheat/wordpress/?p=43">Read More</a>
                </div> <!-- end .description -->
                    </div> <!-- end .slide -->
                                    <div class="slide" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 2; opacity: 0;">
                        <img width="958px" height="340px" alt="More experimental testings" src="http://ftframes.com/delheat/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/vlcsnap-2012-05-13-22h37m19s79-300x129.png">                <div class="featured-top-shadow"></div>
                <div class="featured-bottom-shadow"></div>    
                <div class="featured-description">
                    <div class="feat_desc">
                        <p class="meta-info">Posted by <a rel="author" title="Posts by admin" href="http://ftframes.com/delheat/wordpress/?author=1">admin</a> on Jul 30, 2012</p>
                        <h2 class="featured-title"><a href="http://ftframes.com/delheat/wordpress/?p=10">More experimental testings</a></h2>
                        <p>Lets see how this one turns out… Lets see how this one turLets see how this one turLets see how this one turLets see how this one turLets see how this one turLets see how this one turLets see how this one turLets see how this one tur
&nbsp;
Lets see how this one turLets see how this one turLets see how this one turLets see how this one turLets see how this one turLets see how this one turLets see how...</p>
                    </div>
                    <a class="readmore" href="http://ftframes.com/delheat/wordpress/?p=10">Read More</a>
                </div> <!-- end .description -->
                    </div> <!-- end .slide -->
                                    <div class="slide" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 1; opacity: 0;">
                        <img width="958px" height="340px" alt="Testing this theme with image" src="http://ftframes.com/delheat/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/et_temp/251932_10151043115229294_310983318_n-39277_635x340.jpg">                <div class="featured-top-shadow"></div>
                <div class="featured-bottom-shadow"></div>    
                <div class="featured-description">
                    <div class="feat_desc">
                        <p class="meta-info">Posted by <a rel="author" title="Posts by admin" href="http://ftframes.com/delheat/wordpress/?author=1">admin</a> on Jul 30, 2012</p>
                        <h2 class="featured-title"><a href="http://ftframes.com/delheat/wordpress/?p=6">Testing this theme with image</a></h2>
                        <p>And this is how it looks, very interesting indeed.And this is how it looks, very interesting indeed.And this is how it looks, very interesting indeed.And this is how it looks, very interesting indeed.And this is how it looks, very interesting indeed.And this is how it looks, very interesting indeed.And this is how it looks, very interesting indeed.And this is how it looks, very interesting...</p>
                    </div>
                    <a class="readmore" href="http://ftframes.com/delheat/wordpress/?p=6">Read More</a>
                </div> <!-- end .description -->
                    </div> <!-- end .slide -->
                    </div> <!-- end #slides -->
</div> <!-- end #featured -->
```

And here is part of my CSS:

```
ul#secondary-menu li { background: url(images/secondary-menu-bg.png) repeat-y top right; }
    ul#secondary-menu a { font-size: 16px; color: #48423f; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; padding: 22px 16px; }
    ul#secondary-menu a:hover { color: #ffffff; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #404747; }
    #second-menu ul.nav li:hover a {color: #ffffff; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #404747; }

    ul#secondary-menu > li.current_page_item > a { color: #919e9e !important; }    

    ul#secondary-menu li ul, #category_mobile_menu { width: 360px !important; padding: 7px 0 10px; background: #fff url(images/content-bg.png); top: 55px !important; -moz-box-shadow:3px 3px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; border-top-left-radius: 0px;-moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px; border-top-right-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px; z-index: 9999px; display: none; }
        ul#secondary-menu ul li, #category_mobile_menu li a { margin: 0 !important; padding: 8px 0 8px 30px !important; width: 150px; float: left; }
            ul#secondary-menu ul li a, #category_mobile_menu a { padding: 0 !important; }

            ul#secondary-menu li:hover ul ul, ul#secondary-menu li.sfHover ul ul { top: -8px !important; left: 180px !important; -moz-border-radius: 8px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px; border-radius: 8px; }
            ul#secondary-menu ul li.even-item { background: none; }


.mfilm:hover{
    background:#ea2e49 !important;
}
.mtv:hover{
    background:#2589cf !important;
}
.mwebvideos:hover{
    background:#5c58ac !important;
}
.manimation:hover{
    background:#43cf61 !important;
}
.manime:hover{
    background:#c142a5 !important;
}
.mmanga:hover{
    background:#e77848 !important;
}
.mcomics:hover{
    background:#e8eb05 !important;
}
.mwriters:hover{
    background:#ff3c75 !important;
}
.mmore:hover{
    background:#4b5571 !important;
}
.mliterature:hover{
    background:#2c8f83 !important;
}
.mgames:hover{
    background:#e34328 !important;
}
.marts:hover{
    background:#cc226a !important;
}
.mcontact:hover{
    background:#9395aa !important;
}

/* ---------- Mega Drop Down --------- */
ul#mega li { padding-right: 0px; background: url(images/secondary-menu-bg.png) repeat-y top right; }

#mega {
list-style:none;
font-weight:bold;
height:2em;

}
#mega li {
padding: 23px 0px;
background:#999;
border:0px solid #000;
float:left;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
}
#mega li:hover {
background:#eee;
border-bottom:0; /* border-bottom:0; and padding-bottom:1px; keeps <li> and <div> connected */
z-index:1; /* shadow above adjacent li */

}
#mega a { font-size: 16px; color: #48423f; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; padding: 22px 16px;}

ul#mega a:hover { color: #FFFFFF; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #404747; }



/* ----------- Hide/Show Div ---------- */
#mega div {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-image: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-color: -moz-use-text-color #48423F #48423F;
    border-right: 1px solid #48423F;
    border-style: none solid solid;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: -999em;
    margin-top: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    width: 496px;
}
/* --------- Within Div Styles --------- */
#mega li:hover div {
    left: -1px;
    top: auto;
}
#mega li.dif:hover div {
    left: -407px;
    top: 72px;
}
#mega li.mmore:hover > a {
    color: #FFFFFF; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #404747; /* Ensures hover on MORE remains */
}
#mega div h2 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #999999;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 10px 0 5px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}
#mega div ticman {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
margin-left:1px;
margin-right:1px;
    width: 495px;
    height: 74px;
    background-image: url(images/morebgwide.png);
    background-size:495px 74px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#mega div p {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 106px;
}
#mega div p a {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.4;
    text-decoration: underline;
    width: 100%;
}
#mega div a:hover, #mega div a:focus, #mega div a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}



/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*--------------[FEATURED SLIDER]-----------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/

#featured { position: relative; padding-bottom: 20px; margin-left: -1px; margin-right: -1px; }    
    a#left-arrow, a#right-arrow { position: absolute; top: 136px; width: 32px; height: 68px; text-indent:-9999px; }
        a#left-arrow { background:url(images/left-arrow.png) no-repeat; left: -32px; }    
        a#right-arrow { background:url(images/right-arrow.png) no-repeat; right: -32px; }
            .featured-top-shadow { background:url(images/featured-top-shadow.png) repeat-x; position: absolute; top:0px; left: 0px; width: 958px; height: 7px; }
            .featured-bottom-shadow { background:url(images/featured-bottom-shadow.png) repeat-x; position: absolute; bottom:0; left: 0; width: 958px; height: 8px; }
            .featured-description { position: absolute; width: 333px; height: 196px; top: 40px; right:54px; background:url(images/featured-description.png); padding: 27px 32px 40px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; }
                .featured-description p.meta-info { font-family: Georgia, serif; font-style: italic; font-size: 12px; color: #747474; }
                    .featured-description p.meta-info a { text-decoration: none; color: #fff; }
                h2.featured-title { font-family: 'Kreon', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: lighter;font-size: 30px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); margin-top: -4px; }
                    h2.featured-title a { text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; }
                .featured-description p { color: #c9c8c8; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); line-height: 19px; }    
                a.readmore { display: block; background: url(images/readmore.png); height: 27px; padding: 0 17px; color: #dfca81; font-size: 12px; line-height: 27px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; text-shadow: none; }
                #featured a.readmore { -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;  }
                    #featured a.readmore:hover { color: #fff; }
```

Although, I would advice overlooking the fiddle for a visual presentation of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/H8FVE/3/

I have been trying to wrap my head around this all day to a point where I almost set my hair on fire. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Off hand it looks like a z-index problem.  Try fooling around with the z-index of the image and/or the nav element.

Comment: I am not familiar with the z-index problem that you proposed. If you get a chance to overlook it, please feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/H8FVE/6/:

Just add

```
#second-menu{
    z-index:4;position:relative;
}
```

That's because `slide` has `z-index:3`, so if you want to see `second-menu`, its `z-index` must be higher.

And you have to add `position:relative` too because `z-index` has no effect on elements with `position:static`.

**Edit**:

I have seen you have

```
#mega div{
    left:-999em;
}
#mega li.dif:hover div {
    left: -407px;
    top: 72px;
}
```

I think it would be better like this:

```
#mega > li.dif > div{
    display:none:
    left: -407px;
    top: 72px;
}
#mega > li.dif:hover > div {
    display: block;
}
```

That's because if you set `left:-999em;` to `#mega div`, you suppose that it won't be shown because -999em is a lot. But if you want to hide it, isn't it better not to display it?

And I have added child selectors (`>`) because in the future maybe you will modify it and add more divs inside `#mega > li.dif > div`; and child selectors should be faster than descendant selectors.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although what is the difference if I add 10 to the z-index for **#mega li:hover {**?

Comment: @Henrik Petterson It's the same. If you add it to `#second-menu`, all of its contents (`#secondary-menu` and all `#mega`, not just `#mega li`) will be affected. And they will always be on top (not only on `:hover`). But there is no defference because when there isn't `:hover`, `#mega`'s contents are not shown.

Comment: Cheers for the reply, can you please provide me more info about the edit you made, about what you found for mega div etc...? How would yours be better? Also, I have upvoted this answer and will accept it as correct answer once I understand the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Use the z-index css attribute to visually layer objects like this in HTML regardless of your DOM tree. I would advise you to test your eventual implementation cross browser though, especially IE7. Damn you IE7 for the extra work you cause us all.

Comment: While I am well aware of the pain IE gives us developers, I am new to the z-index attribute. Are you tell me that if I use any of the proposed solutions posted here, it might not work in IE7?

Comment: Not at all, these are the correct solutions. You need to give the objects you want to layer different z-indexes as described in these answers. The objects with lower values will be behind those with higher ones. The comment about IE7 is just advice because its rendering engine behaves differently to up-to-date browsers in some cases

Comment: I understand, thank you. I would also advice you and anyone else that develops sites to add a disclaimer to all users of IE6-8 to change browser. I have added this to all projects that I have done so far.

Comment: Also, I upvoted this answer although it wasn't a direct solution to my issue.

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad I could help. There was a company recently in Australia(?) who taxed users that used IE7 to place orders - owing to the extra dev time it took to fix IE7 bugs! This is the way forward!

Comment: Hahahaha that is hilarious. Do you have a link for this article? I have to read this. Also, this is quite entertaining: http://saveie6.com

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#mega li:hover {
background:#eee;
border-bottom:0; /* border-bottom:0; and padding-bottom:1px; keeps <li> and <div> connected */
z-index:10; /* shadow above adjacent li */
}
```

I changed the z-index to 10, instead of 1.

http://jsfiddle.net/H8FVE/5/

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked fine. Although I have one question, what is the difference between your solution and the one posted by Oriol?

Comment: Mine is applied to all the *li* elements, where as his is just for that one ID. I didn't have time to go through everything, and this was the first thing that I saw. His is better because it gives you exact control of what to raise over the banner, as mine will raise everything over the banner.

Answer (score 0):

Give #second-menu a z-index of 3

Give "#mega div" a z-index of 2

Give #featured a z-index of 1